# Create a download link with Microsoft IIS

Tags: iis

I want to set up a direct download link using Microsoft IIS. We already have a web page using the IP address that points to a /web folder on our server, but I want to create a separate location on my server where I can put downloadable files such that the client can just type the link and get the download: http://IPADDR/download/filename.zip. Are there any resources on how to do this?

Right now, typing http://IPADDR brings up our simple web page which contains a link that launches an application, again this is bound to the /web folder on our server via IIS.

The FTP port is typically blocked on our client's networks so we have to stick with HTTP. This will be completely programmatic, so no need to have a button or link on a page. I will be using java with a GET command to pull files from the link. I just want to be able to have the web server make these files available to download.

FYI I'm newer to this server stuff so simpler is better! Thank you.

Comment: "We already have a web page using the IP address that points to a /web folder on our server", what's that? Reveal your current IIS settings please (like important portion from applicationHost.config file).

Comment: The web folder houses our existing application website (via a published C# app). What files would be useful here? As I said I'm new at this. Also which ones are safe to put up here without compromising security?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are two ways to achieve your needs.

The first is using Asp.net application. You need to write code for the downloaded file. For example, when the user clicks a button, the logic method corresponding to the button is triggered, and the response to the client is the file specified in the code.

```
        var fileNameToShow = "xxx.zip";
        var fileNameAndPath = "The physical path of the file on the server"
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileNameAndPath);
        file.Refresh();
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            // Send the file to the browser
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename= " + fileNameToShow + "; size=" + file.Length.ToString());
            Response.TransmitFile(fileNameAndPath);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("File does not exist!");
        }
```

[image]

The second is to use the FTP function of IIS. You need to create a site and add FTP publishing to the site. When you visit the site through ftp://domian, you can see all the files in the physical directory of the site on the server, and you can download any file by clicking on it.(It also can download through link,such as ftp://domain/filename.zip)
[image]

Comment: The FTP port is typically blocked on our client's networks so we have to stick with HTTP. This will be completely programmatic, so no need to have a button or link on a page. I will be using java with a GET command to pull files from the link. I just want to be able to have the web server make these files available to download.

Comment: you can set the response like the first method. If you don't want to set it in the application, you need to use the IIS Url rewrite module and set the value of action to “attachment; filename=xxx.txt”.