# How to allow user to download file that's in website's root directory?

Tags: vb.net, iis

I have a website in IIS with a .csv file sitting in the root directory, is there a way to let users download the file?  I've tried the following:

```
Using client as New System.Net.WebClient()

    Dim path as string = Server.MapPath("~/")
    client.DownloadFile(path, "some_file.csv")

End Using
```

But this downloads the file to the server, it doesn't give it to the user to download. How can I do this?  And the .csv is already created, so I can't export some data grid to excel.

Comment: Download from the web to the client?

Comment: Show a page with the hyper link pointing to that file and then the web browser will be happy to download that when the user clicks the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download file to client, just set response in code or configure ftp on server. You can refer to my another answer.

[Download file from IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65104010/14162739)

WebClient.DownloadFile() will download file from another server to local server. The first parameter is URL. And the identity of application pool should set to local system.